# Is Babel being used as compiler (AOT or JIT) in angular 5

Tags: angular, angular5, angular2-aot

Do we need Babel in an Angular 5 application? What AOT or JIT is being used internally to compile?

Comment: Where could you find Babel in Anuglar 5?

Comment: @RK6 did my answer solve your issue?

Comment: Yes, thank you for the clarification @tatsu

Comment: thank you! would care to mark me as answer (checkmark next to the answer) so that in the future, people searching for answers with the same problem will see this as resolved in the results and click on it instead of ignoring it? thanks :)

Comment: Done it. Thank you

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You don't need to worry about babel in an angular 2+ application.

You configure the ECMAscript level in the tsconfig.app.json file in you project.

(be sure you initiated your project with angular's [angular-cli](https://cli.angular.io/))

example (angular 8):

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "types": []
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

example (angular 5) :

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "module": "es2015", //<-- can aslo be es5 es6 es7
    "types": []
  },
  "exclude": [
    "test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

typescript, angular's filesystem includes a very complete bundle of all the other goodies there exist in the JS biosphere :

- ECMAscript (ergo babel)
- coffeescript
- ...

Comment: `error TS6046: Argument for '--module' option must be: 'none', 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system', 'umd', 'es6', 'es2015', 'esnext'.`

Comment: in latest version of angular (8) module is not even there. try updated version (or just use angular-cli to create that file, don't make it yourself)

Comment: forgive me the ignorance tatsu, but where did you configure ECMAScript in Angular 8+??, in Angular 5 it is visible that it was in modules, but I didn't see in angular 8 explicitly